# Lowest value of simple function: $\sqrt{x}-\ln{x}$

Tags: calculus

$$y=\sqrt{x}-\ln{x}$$ as noted when graphed, the function has a lowest $y$ value when $x=4$. Can I have a rigorous proof of why this is the case?

Comment: We will have to use calculus tools, precalculus is not enough.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Should I edit the tab there?

Comment: The derivative of [tex]\sqrt{x}- ln(x)[/tex] is [tex]\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}- \frac{1}{x}= \frac{\sqrt{x}- 2}{2x}[/quote].  For any positive x, the denominator is positive so its sign is that of the numerator.  For x< 4, [tex]\sqrt{x}[/tex] is less than 2 so the numerator is negative,  That means the function value is [b]decreasing[/b].  For x> 4, [tex]\sqrt{x}[/tex] is larger than 2 so the numerator is positive. That means the function value is [b]increasing[/b].

Comment: You edited, calculus is fine.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have both calculus  and pre-calculus as tags. It's either one or the other.

Comment: $\min \sqrt{x} - \ln x $, with $x = y^2$ it's equivalent to $\min f(y) = y - 2 \ln y$, $f'(y) = 1-\frac{2}{y}$,  $f'(2) = 0$ and $y \ne 2 \implies f'(y) \ne 0 $, and $\lim_{y \to 0} f(y) = +\infty$, $\lim_{y \to \infty} f(y) = +\infty$, thus the minimum is at $y=2 \implies x=4$

Comment: I do not know what pre-calculus is, but if one knows that $\ln t\le t-1$ it is enough to solve the problem without derivatives.

Comment: @A.G. does it even make sence to hope defining the constant $e$ and thus $\ln x$ before derivatives ?

Comment: @reuns Well... Logarithms, (from Greek λόγος *ratio*, and αριθμός *number*), the indices of the ratios of numbers to one another; being a series of numbers in arithmetical progression, corresponding to others in geometrical progression; by means of which, arithmetical calculations can be made with much more ease and expedition then otherwise. (c) Encyclopædia Britannica, vol. 10, p. 119, 1797. Though I do not know how to use it...

Comment: $\log_2(n)$ is easy to define, $\log_2(x)$ too, but the constant $e$ comes from the fact that $(e^x)' = e^x$, or from infinite series... I don't know too what is "pre-calculus", but I don't think it concerns infinite series nor derivatives nor integrals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that we're going to need to being in the big bad calculus for this particular proof. Let $f(x) = \sqrt{x} - \ln x$ then we have $$f'(x) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} - \frac{1}{x} = \frac{\sqrt{x}-2}{2x}.$$ This means that the function has an extrema at $f'(x) = 0\iff \sqrt{x} = 2 \implies x = 4$.

Since we have $f(1) = 1  > 2 - \ln 4 = f(4)$ and $f(16) = 4 - \ln 16 > 2 - \ln 4 = f(4)$ then the point must be a minimum.

Comment: I believe you're missing a square root sign in your $f'(x)$ expression

Comment: @Brenton, Woopsie daisy, thanks! :-)

Comment: @molarmass... I must be very tired. Wow.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be the function defined by $x\mapsto\sqrt{x}-\ln x$. Since

$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}-\frac{1}{x}=\frac{\sqrt{x}-2}{2x}$$

vanishes only for $x=4$, and $f''(4)=\frac{\sqrt{x}-2(\sqrt{x}-2)}{4x^2}_{|x=4}=\frac{1}{8}>0$ it follows that $f$ reaches its minimum value at $x=4$.